# Result is no longer the same while aggregating data

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

I've been using the following function to aggregate Data:

```
private Collection<MyObject> aggregate(List<MyObject> objects) {
Map<String, MyObject> map = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();
for (MyObject current : objects) {
   String key = String.format("%s:%s", current.gender, current.state);
   MyObject aggregated = map.get(key);
   if (aggregated == null) {
       aggregated = new MyObject();
       aggregated.gender = current.gender;
       aggregated.state = current.state;
       map.put(key, aggregated);
   }
   aggregated.quantity += current.quantity;
   aggregated.salary += current.salary;
}
return map.values();
}
```

MyObject Structure:

```
public class MyObject {
 private String gender;
 private  String state;
 private int quantity;
 private int Salary;
 //getters & setters}
```

but because I had to declare MyObject attributes as Private, I changed it to the following:

```
      private static Collection<MyObject> aggregate(List<MyObject> objects) {
        Map<String, MyObject> map = new HashMap<String, MyObject>();
        for (MyObject current : objects) {
           String key = String.format("%s:%s", current.gender, current.state);
           MyObject aggregated = map.get(key);
           if (aggregated == null) {
               aggregated = new MyObject();
               aggregated.setGender(current.getGender());
               aggregated.setState(current.state);
               map.put(key, aggregated);
           }
           int quantity=0,salary=0;
            quantity=quantity+aggregated.getQuantity();
            salary= salary+aggregated.getSalary(); 
           aggregated.setQuantity(quantity);
           aggregated.setSalary(salary);

        }
        return map.values();
    }
```

so it's no longer giving me the desired result.

Comment: what is the "desired result" ?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon im not using equals() and hashCode()

Comment: @hamzaspecter - You may not but `HashMap` will. It was a silly comment anyway because your keys are `String`s. Will delete it.

Comment: Hint: please read a bit about OO design. You are doing exactly the wrong thing. You should not use getters to retrieve a value, change that value and write it back using a setter. Instead - put methods on your classes that allow you to do what you need. For example you could add a method `aggregateWith(MyObject otherGuy)` ... or even better, you create a method that "merges" two MyObjects; into a NEW one.

Comment: And side note: what you are experiencing right now is exactly what happens when you use StackOverflow as "code generator". In your first question ... you asked for a solution; and you got code without any explanations (which is actually pretty surprising and doesn't happen too often here). But of course, you are a beginner, and now you struggle with the next problem. So, what I am saying: there are no detours. You have to **learn** the basic stuff; and asking for solutions is not an efficient way to **learn**. Like: when learning how to shoot; not a good idea to simply ask for a loaded weapon.

Comment: @Jägermeister i don't know if im getting right your point. can you explain yourself a little more

Comment: @Jägermeister im not using stack as code generator, but as you said im a beginner and trying to learn from the best.

Comment: I am only telling you that you are using an inefficient approach.

Answer (score 1):

In your first fragment you are doing something to add `current` to `aggregated`. In your second you are only referencing `aggregated` so probably not right.

Something like:

```
        }
        aggregated.setQuantity(aggregated.getQuantity() + current.getQuantity());
        aggregated.setSalary(aggregated.getSalary() + current.getSalary());
```

should be better.

Comment: no, in my second code, it's adding the content of all the fields, except that im looking to do so just with fields having the same gender and the same state

Comment: @hamzaspecter - Your second fragment **does not aggregate**, it leaves the `aggregate.quantity` and `aggregate.salary` at `0`. You say `+aggregated.getQuantity()` when you should use `+current.getQuantity()`.